# python Excel как корректно вставить формулу (содержащую кириллицу) в ячейку

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, excel-формулы

Проблема при вставке формулы (хранит кириллицу и др спец символы) в ячейку , грешу на это :(
Как решить проблему с строкой(формула) ?
Возможно надо попробовать использовать другую библиотеку для работы с Excel

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# openpyxl Version: 3.1.2

from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'working_test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

# Формула в строковом типе с которой проблема
formula = '=(SUM(Состояния!$B$2+Состояния!$B$3+ЕСНД(ИНДЕКС(DowntimeReasonDuration[#Все];ПОИСКПОЗ("Короткие простои";DowntimeReasonDuration[[#Все];[Причина простоя]];0);3);0)*100%)/Состояния!$F$1)'
# вышестояшая формула не может сохранится в ячейке / приводит не корретное сохранение файла

formula_1 = '=(SUM(B1:B2))'    # тестовая формула проходит норм

ws['W22'] = formula    # вставка формулы в данную ячейку


wb.save('working_test_2.xlsx')   # сохраняем файл
```

Comment: а то, что у вас формулы операнды и латиницей и кириллицей - так и задумано?

Comment: да все верно, такая вот формула

Comment: А в чем проблема сразу на латинице формулу записать? Если я правильно помню, то в самом Excel все формулы сохраняются в латинице(и не важно на каком языке записать). А все библиотеки вставляют формулы как есть, то есть трансляцию не делают, отсюда и ошибка... Excel просто не может прочитать формулы на кириллице.

Comment: хорошее замечание попробую в латиницу переделать :)